# Sending Json response as String and Integers...

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "UpdateRequest": {
        "SAASAS": {
            "SPO2": "99.00000",
            "VitalGroupID": "1219",
            "Temperature": "36.6666666666667",            
        },
        "Modified": 1,
        "ID": 25465
    }
}
```

How can i send VitalGroupID and Temperature as Integer instead of String.... This is the request that get's formed after i hit submit button.

Comment: Isn't JSON always sent as String? I think you must cast the type manually

Comment: @das: JSON is a textual notation, just like JavaScript source code is a textual notation. He's talking about `"VitalGroupID": "1219"` (which defines a property with the *string* value `"1219"`) as opposed to `"VitalGroupID": 1219` (which defines the property with the *numeric* value `1219`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, json is untyped, so you can't send it as an integer, it has to be a string. javascript objects are a little less strict, so what you have their will evaluate to a javascript object, but no strict json parser will be able to understand it.

The best you can do is to convert fields that you know are numbers on the client side using parseInt.

e.g. `sonObj["UpdateRequest"]["SAASAS"]["VitalGroupID"] = parseInt(jsonObj["UpdateRequest"]["SAASAS"]["VitalGroupID"], 10);`

Comment: Looks like ECMA-404 standard does make a difference between string and number in JSON: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to show the code that's creating the request when you click the button. Basically, if the object you're serializing contains numbers rather than strings, the resulting JSON will have numbers instead of strings. So the problem is that the object you're serializing has strings instead.

But for instance, if you're getting these values from HTML input fields or similar, e.g.:

```
UpdateRequest.SAASAS.VitalGroupID = someInputElement.value;
```

...`value` is *always* a string. You'll need to parse it:

```
UpdateRequest.SAASAS.VitalGroupID = parseInt(someInputElement.value, 10);
```

Note that it's best to use `parseInt` and to give it the radix (the number base, usually 10), else you run into issues with numbers written as "08" and similar.

Answer (score 1):

JSON supports numbers as values.  So:

```
var r = {
    "UpdateRequest": {
        "SAASAS": {
            "SPO2": "99.00000",
            "VitalGroupID": "1219",
            "Temperature": "36.6666666666667",            
        },
        "Modified": 1,
        "ID": 25465
    }
}
r.UpdateRequest.SAASAS.VitalGroupID = +r.UpdateRequest.SAASAS.VitalGroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Number(jsonObject.UpdateRequest.SAASAS.VitalGroupID);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle it in the Client side (As you have mentioned JSON,JAvascript). You can do the following after u parse the JSON object. `parseInt(UpdateRequest.SAASAS.VitalGroupID,10)` or `UpdateRequest.SAASAS.VitalGroupID*1` Adopt the same for the "temparature" variable too.