# Sending Integer to Json Call

Tags: android, json, object, integer, call

Actually "Strictly speaking, json is untyped, so you can't send it as an integer, it has to be a string." is said in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858293/sending-json-response-as-string-and-integers) 2 YEARS AGO. So i wonder if there are any changes in JSON to get integer from a JSON Object. I try to call integer by this way;

```
static int versionCode=0;
jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject queryJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("query");
versionCode =queryJSONObject.getInt("versionCode");
```

And the JSON is like this;

**{"query":{"versionCode":1,....}}**

Can anything be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you asking about sending or receiving/getting the integer? Your title is contradicting with your code. Also, maybe related: [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: You are right, it should be receiving. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

follow this [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) you can use getString() function to get value and latter you can convert it like this **int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");** in integer according to your need

Answer (score -1):

JSON has a number element, see JSON.org
[image]

JSON is a sequence of characters. But I disagree that a number is a string in this context. IMHO for me a string is wrapped in double quotes (which a number isn't).

Your code should work: `json.getInt("versionCode")` [Source from Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: There is no problem in string calls, when l add that part app stops, when I comment it out, app works. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Can you add a Try/Catch clausule and see what Exception is thrown (or look in LogCat)