# sending numeric JSON response in node/express

Tags: node.js, express

If I have this response -

```
{
  type: "2",
  userId: "123"
}
```

While sending the response, I want the values to convert to numeric. Is there any way in node/express to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `parseInt()`?

Comment: Try this question -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858293/sending-json-response-as-string-and-integers

Comment: I don't want to convert it field by field. Isn't there any other way where I send my JSON in the function and it returns the updated JSON?

Answer (score 0):

> var _ = require('underscore');
>
> var data = {
>       type: "2",
>       userId: "123" };
>
> var result = _.keys(data);
>
> result.forEach(function (key) {
>       data[key] = Number(data[key]) });
>
> console.log(data);

Answer (score 0):

we can use parseInt() to convert string to int type.

```
var data = { type: parseInt("2"), userId:  parseInt("2") };

response.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly answer is

```
var a = {type: "2", userId: "123", text: "ABC"};
res.send(JSON.stringify(a, function(key, value) { return parseInt(value) || value}));
```

Express have special method to stringify object and send it - `res.json`, but this method doesn't support replacer function.