# How to get json from HTML form and keep type of input

Tags: python, html, json, request

I can get json from HTML form but the problem is that all of value in side json are convert to string type.
I have try both
result = json.dumps(request.form)
result = jsonify(request.form)
but result still be the same.
[HTML form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtXDz.png)
[Output Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HTNX.png)

Is there any way to get the result like this 
{
  "department": "sales", 
  "donation": 1538, 
  "firstName": "abc", 
  "lastName": "ccc"
}

HTML Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
<div class="container">
        <form action="/display" method="post" id="employForm"
        <fieldset>
        <label>First Name
          <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Joe" required>
        </label>
        <label>Last Name
          <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Schmoe" required>
        </label>
        <label>Homeless cat donation
          <input type="number" name="donation" id="donation" placeholder=1234 required>
        </label>

        <label>
        Department
          <select name="department" required>
            <option value="sales">Sales</option>
            <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
            <option value="developer">Developer</option>
            <option value="business">Business Relations</option>
            <option value="sysAdmin">Systems Administration</option>
            <option value="operation">Operation</option>
          </select>
        </label>
            Thanks
        </fieldset>
      <button class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" form="employForm">SUBMIT!</button>
    </form>
    </body>
  </div>
 </html>
```

This is the python flask code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():
     return render_template('layout.html')

@app.route('/display', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def display():   
    result = jsonify(request.form)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: I suggest that you try doing json.loads to first convert it back to a dictionary and then json.dumps. How does it turn out?

Comment: Thanks, but the result is { "department": "sales", "donation": "1538", "firstName": "abc", "lastName": "ccc" }
Value of donation does not keep format as number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking notes from this Answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858293/sending-json-response-as-string-and-integers#:~:text=Strictly%20speaking%2C%20json%20is%20untyped,be%20able%20to%20understand%20it.)

JSON is untyped. Anything sent in JSON format will be converted to a string; so its not possible to send the `donation` value as an integer.